# Variance of the product of two normal variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, variance, expected-value, chi-squared-distribution

out of curiosity, I wonder if there is a solution for the expectation of the product of two chi-square variables (or the variance of the product of the normals).

Say: Let $(X,Y)$ be jointly normal, with mean 0 and covariance matrix $\Sigma = \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{1}^{2} & \sigma_{12}\\
\sigma_{12} & \sigma_{2}^{2}
\end{pmatrix} $.
I know the expecation of $XY$, $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\sigma_{12}$, but how about the variance of $XY$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[(XY-\sigma_{12})^2]$?

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: One approach might be to write $X$ and $Y$ in terms of $U$ and $V$ with independent normal distributions

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/593443/77222

Comment: Yes I think that post answers my question! Thanks guys!!!